# How to implement a vertical liquid layout with divs

Tags: html, css, layout, liquid-layout

My website has three components:

- a fixed height header that spans the width of the screen
- a fixed width nav under the header on the left that spans the remaining height of the screen
- a content area to the right of the nav that takes up any remaining space.

I understand how to implement the horizontal aspect of the liquid layout so that the nav remains fixed while the content area takes up remaining width, but I don't understand how to implement the vertical aspect of liquid layout so that both the nav and content area take up *at least* the remainder of the height and *at most* the height of their content (assuming that this is taller than the screen less the header height).

Possible with divs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Take a look at [Ryan Fait's sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/), and my previous [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775013/center-footer-fixed-at-the-bottom-ie/2776201#2776201).

Comment: By that sure does get me close - but check out what happens when you fill in the .wrapper div with lots of content.  Once it gets tall enough it writes over the footer :-( sadness ensues.

Comment: @糞_爺 - Do you have a link? I'll take a look at it if you do. I haven't had that problem myself. We use this technique on [our site](http://www.hl7.org) and haven't had any problems.

Comment: After looking at http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ again I see that it works fine on his site so I just have to figure out how my usage differs from his.  Thanks for the offer.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/HcBKV/embedded/result/

There are generally two ways to go about it. One is with setting the height and width to 100%, the other is with stretching by means of position absolute and making it a fixed length from each side.